# In appium, how do i use a test as a dependenciy to another test without running it all the time?

Tags: python, appium

I'm trying to create a few tests in appium, but when i first run the application i have to pass through terms of use screen and first run screens.

Since i only have to run these steps just once, i'm having some hard time to run other tests (when i already ran these screens).

Any ideas of how can i do it?

```
import os, unittest, time
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.1'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = '0429058934'
        desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'mypath'))
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = ''
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.MainActivity'
        desired_caps['fullReset'] = True
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def first_run(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("p_agreement_btn").click()
        next = self.driver.find_element_by_id("next_text")
        next.click()
        next.click()
        next.click()
        next.click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("btn_ok").click()

    def test_optimization(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("new_powerpro_tab_view_text").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("optimization_button").click()       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Tests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using UnitTest framework for python which is not support dependency like TestNg. if you want to create dependent test then you user Proboscis testing framework, it has same feature like TestNg. Go though above link on read document specially annotations like " @test(depends_on=[UserTests.successful_login])"

Answer (score -1):

For that you can used Proboscis.

Refer link : https://pythonhosted.org/proboscis/

Comment: please provide much more info about the link.

Comment: You are using UnitTest framework for python which is not support dependency like TestNg. if you want to create dependent test then you user Proboscis testing framework, it has same feature like TestNg. Go though above link on read document specially annotations like " @test(depends_on=[UserTests.successful_login])"